# TypeError when I run collectatic to save the static in S3 bucket using django

Tags: django, amazon-s3, typeerror, boto3, collectstatic

I'm a bit new to django and I'm trying to run collectstatic from the terminal (python manage.py collectstatic) in order to collect the static files in the S3 bucket but I getting the following error:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\storages\backends\s3boto3.py:282: UserWarning: The default behavior of S3Boto3Storage is insecure and will change in django-storages 2.0. By default files and new buckets are saved with an ACL of 'public-read' (globally publicly readable). Version 2.0 will default to using the bucket's ACL. To opt into the new behavior set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None, otherwise to silence this warning explicitly set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL.
  "The default behavior of S3Boto3Storage is insecure and will change "
```

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings.
This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

```
Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 199, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 124, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 354, in copy_file
    if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 260, in delete_file
    if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\storages\backends\s3boto3.py", line 532, in exists
    self.connection.meta.client.head_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=name)
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\storages\backends\s3boto3.py", line 315, in connection
    verify=self.verify,
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\boto3\session.py", line 389, in resource
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\boto3\session.py", line 263, in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\session.py", line 839, in create_client
    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 86, in create_client
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 328, in _get_client_args
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\args.py", line 47, in get_client_args
    endpoint_url, is_secure, scoped_config)
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\args.py", line 117, in compute_client_args
    service_name, region_name, endpoint_url, is_secure)
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 402, in resolve
    service_name, region_name)
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\regions.py", line 122, in construct_endpoint
    partition, service_name, region_name)
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\regions.py", line 141, in _endpoint_for_partition
    if self._region_match(partition, region_name):
  File "C:\Users\Elena\Desktop\Curso\4th Module\ecommerce2\.venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\regions.py", line 159, in _region_match
    return re.compile(partition['regionRegex']).match(region_name)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
(.venv)
```

Steps that I have followed:

1. I have installed django-storages and boto3

```
pip install django-storages
pip install boto3
```

2. I have added 'storages' to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py
3. I have created 'custom_storage.py'

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION
```

3. I have added the following to settings.py

```
   AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
       'Expires': 'Thu, 31 Dec 2099 20:00:00 GMT',
       'CacheControl': 'max-age=94608000'
    }

    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'elena-ecommerce'
    AWS_S3_REGION_NAME  = 'eu-west-2',
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID")
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")

    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

     STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
     STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storage.StaticStorage'

     STATIC_URL = '/static/'
     STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),)
```

4. And the I have run the following command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the settings file where you have mentioned as `AWS_S3_REGION_NAME  = 'eu-west-2',` there is a comma after **eu-west-2**, remove that and it will work. The comma after the string create a tuple like this, **('eu-west-2',)** instead of string, whereas the re match expects a string

I just mentioned a sample

```
>>> AWS_S3_REGION_NAME  = 'eu-west-2',
>>> print(AWS_S3_REGION_NAME)
('eu-west-2',)

>>> AWS_S3_REGION_NAME  = 'eu-west-2'
>>> print(AWS_S3_REGION_NAME)
eu-west-2
```

Refer: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: Thanks a lot Sajeer Noohukannu! Removing comma solved the problem :)